# An issue with bisection algorithm (beginner)

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    
    float num;
    
    printf(" Enter a number to find it's sqaure root: ");
    scanf(" %f",&num);
    
    
    double acc;
    acc = 0.000001;
    float min = 1;
    float max;
    max = num;
    float ans = (min + max)/2;
    int count = 1;
    printf(" num of guesses : %d  max: %f  min: %f\n",count,max,min);
 while(abs((ans*ans)-num)>=acc){
     count++;
    printf(" num of guesses : %d  max: %f  min: %f\n",count,max,min);
    if (ans*ans>num){
    max = ans;
    }
    else {
    min = ans;
    }
    ans = (min + max)/2;

}
 printf("\n\n The number of Guesses are: %d\n",count);
 printf(" %f is close to the Square root of %f",ans,num);
}
```

When I run this code every thing goes well but I notice a strange thing:

***This is the result***

Enter a number to find it's sqaure root: 100
num of guesses : 1  max: 100.000000  min: 1.000000
num of guesses : 2  max: 100.000000  min: 1.000000
num of guesses : 3  max: 50.500000  min: 1.000000
num of guesses : 4  max: 25.750000  min: 1.000000
num of guesses : 5  max: 13.375000  min: 1.000000
num of guesses : 6  max: 13.375000  min: 7.187500
num of guesses : 7  max: 10.281250  min: 7.187500
num of guesses : 8  max: 10.281250  min: 8.734375
num of guesses : 9  max: 10.281250  min: 9.507812
num of guesses : 10  max: 10.281250  min: 9.894531

The number of Guesses are: 10
9.991211 is close to the Square root of 100.000000

Why are the first two min and max staying constant while I am averaging them inside the loop?

Comment: In the second `printf`, the first time in the loop nothing has changed (apart from `count`). Perhaps you meant to put it later in the loop.

Comment: Because the first output line is before the loop begins, and the second one is at the start of the loop before the first approximation has been made. Doh!

Comment: I am sorry :0 I am just a beginner, and still need to get sharper in noticing and problem solving

Comment: If the code indentation was nice, things like this are easier to see.